# Did Pasch and Peano use models for their axiomatic systems in geometry?

Tags: geometry, model-theory, mathematical-modeling, axiomatic-geometry

I'm trying to track down the introduction of models in order to get a better understanding of the modern axiomatic method in general. So far it seems to be Hilbert that first created and made use of a model as a concept to prove the consistency of his axioms, I can't find any information that suggests that Pasch or Peano did the same.

Additionally, I can't find any details on Hilbert's model (which seems to be based on the real numbers?). Any input or redirections to where I can read more specifically about his model is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: No idea about Peano and Pash, but one should mention the unit disk and upper plane models published by Poincaré for hyperbolic geometry also around 1900.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned this. The concept of using models to prove consistency actually seems to originate with the study of non-euclidean geometry (hyperbolic geometry more specifically), prior to the modern axiomatic method much developed by Pasch, Peano and Hilbert. Eugenio Beltrami, János Bolyai and Nikolai Lobachevsky seems to be key figures, though I'm not sure the second two provided any models in that sence.

Comment: Have you seen this reference :https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2469418/305862 ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I actually knew a little bit about Veblen's work since before, in which he provides what I'd like to refer to as an arithmetic model. But similarly to what is mentioned in that post, I would've liked his work to be more explanatory in how he implements this model (as to how he implements any model for the sake of proving consistency). At the same time I figure his work was not meant to be introductory. Thank you for the reference